# how to keep a number with a specials letter ahead

Tags: r

I have a data that looks like this: and I only want to get the number that start with `H` out?
[image]

The sample data can be build using codes:

```
df2<-structure(list(N1 = c("H#7", "H#7 W#8", "H#7,H#8", "H#07", "#H/7", 
"#/\\W7", "W#16 A/H# 2 A/H #4", "H7 and H8")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Are there more patterns

Comment: not really. When I tried to solve it, I separate N1 using `W|H` and then process data to get number out, then unite them back to `outcome`. Seems way too complicate for such small step. :( My real data have more than 5 inputs.

Comment: Please note that you did not update your expected output when you updated your sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to extract only the characters that start with 'H' followed by # or `/` if any and one or more digits (`\\d+`), then remove the characters other than the digits with in the `list` with `str_remove_all`, create a condition with `if/else` to paste the `#` as prefix after converting to `numeric`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df2 %>%
   mutate(Outcome = map_chr(str_extract_all(N1, "H[#/ ]*?\\d+"),
     ~ {
     tmp <- as.numeric(str_remove_all(.x, "[H#/]"))
       if(length(tmp) > 0) str_c("#", tmp, collapse=", ") else ""
   }))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#  N1                   Outcome 
#  <chr>                <chr>   
#1 "H#7"                "#7"    
#2 "H#7 W#8"            "#7"    
#3 "H#7,H#8"            "#7, #8"
#4 "H#07"               "#7"    
#5 "#H/7"               "#7"    
#6 "#/\\W7"             ""      
#7 "W#16 A/H# 2 A/H #4" "#2, #4"
#8 "H7 and H8"          "#7, #8"
```

---

Or use a regex lookaround to make this more compact

```
df2 %>%
 mutate(tmp = map_chr(str_extract_all(N1,
       '(?<=H[#/]?)\\d+|(?<=H# )\\d+|(?<=H #)\\d+'), 
   ~ if(length(.x) > 0)  str_c('#', as.numeric(.x), collapse=", ") else ""))
```

Comment: what if #6 is `#/\\H7`? one more patten with "\" in front

Comment: @Stataq it is returning the #7 for that case (i tested)

Comment: I update the codes for data, there is one case I forgot to put in. I put it in #6. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach with the more generic `\\W` non-word character type:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% 
  mutate(Outcome = map(str_extract_all(N1,"H\\W*[0-9]+"),
                       ~str_remove_all(.x,"\\D") %>% 
                         as.numeric %>%
                         map_chr(~paste0("#",.x))) %>% 
                      map_chr(~paste(.x,collapse = ", ")))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  N1                   Outcome 
  <chr>                <chr>   
1 "H#7"                "#7"    
2 "H#7 W#8"            "#7"    
3 "H#7,H#8"            "#7, #8"
4 "H#07"               "#7"    
5 "#H/7"               "#7"    
6 "#/\\W7"             ""      
7 "W#16 A/H# 2 A/H #4" "#2, #4"
8 "H7 and H8"          "#7, #8"
```

Comment: The [stringr cheat sheet](https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf) explains all the special match characters. Remember that you have to double escape \ in R. In brief, `\\W*` matches 0 or more non-word characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(Output = str_extract_all(N1,"H[^H]*\\d+") %>% 
                        map_chr(.,~paste(str_extract(.,pattern="\\d+"),collapse=", ")) )
df2
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  N1                   Output
  <chr>                <chr> 
1 "H#7"                "7"   
2 "H#7 W#8"            "7"   
3 "H#7,H#8"            "7, 8"
4 "H#07"               "07"  
5 "#H/7"               "7"   
6 "#/\\W7"             ""    
7 "W#16 A/H# 2 A/H #4" "2, 4"
8 "H7 and H8"          "7, 8"
```